# How can I start off-block transaction in LoafWallet?

Tags: litecoin, lightning-network

Lightening network promise, basic principle is, transaction not need to add to blockchain but cumulate them and submit all together for a reduced amount of fee. How can I choose such an option in `LoafWallet`? I have not seen such an option in the app.

Comment: you probably mean `LoafWallet`? from [loafwallet.org](https://loafwallet.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Lightning Network is not even live and therefor not supported yet.*

Actually the Lightning Network does not quite work as you described.

You create a opening transaction which locks the funds in a multisig with the other participant. It's possible to withdraw the funds only after a specified time or to sign a transaction which pays both participants according to their needs and is spendable earlier.  If both participants agree, they sign the transaction.  The channel can then be closed by broadcasting the transaction **or** they can continue to keep creating a new version of the transaction with pays them different amounts depending on their needs.

This means you can have nearly unlimited transactions for the cost of one opening and one closing transaction.

However this is not live on mainnet (not for Bitcoin, not for Litecoin) and Loa**f**Wallet doesn't support it yet.

Comment: `Super Bitcoin` will support `Lightning network` too, and it will release on 17th December. Is it the first implementation of `Lightning network`?

Comment: Super Bitcoin might be released on the 17th December and they might claim to support the LN once it's finished (a fork of a client ofc). But they are definitely not the first to implement the LN.

Comment: Do you know any implementation of `Lightening network` that really works?

Comment: This article (published less than a hour ago) might be interesting regarding this topic: “Lightning Protocol 1.0: Compatibility Achieved ✅” https://medium.com/@lightning_network/lightning-protocol-1-0-compatibility-achieved-f9d22b7b19c4 Make sure to mark this question as answered if this helps.

Comment: This video is so bad quality. If someone could not talk understandable English, why he does not add subtitle for it?